# jQuery ajax $(xml).find() works in IE but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, post, dynamics-crm-2011

I am making a FetchXML request to CRM from a webresource hosted on the same CRM instance

This code works in IE but doesn't in Chrome...Why?

```js
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'xml',
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        url: path,
        data: fetchRequest,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(
                "SOAPAction",
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute"
            ); //without the SOAPAction header, CRM will return a 500 error
        }
    }).done(
         function(data){
           $(data).find("a\\:Entity").each(function () {
            // loop entered in IE but not in chrome
           }
         }
     );
```

EDIT

The problem isn't with the ajax call the problem is with the .find() not getting the node from the returned xml.

So to be clear I get what looks like the same xml back from the request in each browser but the find method here

```
$(data).find('a\\Entity')
```

returns no items in chrome...it works perfectly in IE.

Comment: Check console for errors (by pressing f12)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I have found the problem

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/155

jQuery find() has problems because of different implementations of selectSingleNode in different browsers.

This bug says its fixed but I don't think it is.

**EDIT**

I found that making the selector look like this seems to work

```
$(xml).find("a\\:Entity, Entity")
```

It's a bit of a hack but it solves my particular problem

Comment: +1, just ran into this myself. Nice work. Still works in IE too.

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely need to hook up to `.fail` to see if it's returning an error. You should be able to attach it to the end of the `.done` function, something like

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'xml',
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    url: path,
    data: fetchRequest,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
            "SOAPAction",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute"
        ); //without the SOAPAction header, CRM will return a 500 error
    }
}).done(
     function(data){
       $(data).find("a\\:Entity").each(function () {
        // loop entered in IE but not in chrome
       }
     }
 ).fail(function(p1, p2, p3){
    ...
});
```

Note - If the fail works like the old "error" function did then there should be multiple parameters you can allow the fail function to accept as well, the second and third giving you more detail about the error.

Beyond capturing the fail, I recall a problem with chrome and asynchronous mode so you could also try setting the async flag to false after the dataType flag. Something like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'xml',
    async: false,
    .... etc
```

The only other problem I've read about chrome is problems with jsonp, but you're using xml here so that obviously isn't the problem.

Comment: No the problem isn't with the ajax call the problem is with the .find() not getting the node from the returned xml

Comment: Possibly misread your question then. To be honest if you're trying to do something like this all via javascript look into Daniel Cai's excellent tool. He has all of this already wrapped: http://xrmsvctoolkit.codeplex.com/ (or you can also grab the full version which is here: http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Yeah it was poorly worded...your info was useful for other reasons anyway, thanks.